# Close platform after closing a pop-up | JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

So I have 2 stages, one is the main stage and the other is a pop-up screen. When the pop-up screen shows up you can close it by pressing the 'x' at the upper-left (or upper-right depending on your OS). Is there a way to close the main stage whenever you close the pop-up screen?

Comment: Call `Platform.exit()` in the close hook (`popup.setOnCloseRequest(...)`).

Comment: `onCloseRequest` is not really the correct event here: that is called when the user clicks on the close button for the popup. It can be vetoed at that point, so the popup might not really close. You should use `onHidden()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stage` and `Popup` inherit an [`onHidden` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onHiddenProperty) from `Window`. This is a handler that is invoked immediately after the window is hidden (by any mechanism). You can call `Platform.exit()` in the handler in order to exit the application:

```
popup.setOnHidden(event -> Platform.exit());
```

Note that `Platform.exit()` is generally preferred to `System.exit(0)`: calling `System.exit(...)` will not allow the `Application`'s `stop()` method to be called, so you may bypass any resource clean-up your application is performing.

Comment: Which one is better to use between `Platform.exit()` and `System.exit(...)` in general cases? I have read some Stackoverflow questions and found that [some people](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938279/javafx-application-still-running-after-close) are using both. And some of them are not interested using it as sometime it may not work.

Comment: Thank you very much, this did the job!

Answer (score 1):

There have a Event named `setOnCloseRequest`. If you are opening an `Alert` pop-up window.

```
Alert popup = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
```

Then your solution is:

```
alert.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<DialogEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(DialogEvent t)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Else if you want to close another window with it's owner, then just use it's `stage` and replace `DialogEvent` with `WindowEvent`.

Comment: `onCloseRequest` is not the correct event to use here: it only gets invoked if there is an "external" request to close the window; usually this means the user presses the native window close button. It is possible to veto the request, in which case the `onCloseRequest` handler gets invoked even though the window does not close.